# Neo4j Cypher exists with all condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to properly write the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (p:Profile)-[hvo:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN [1,2,3,4,5] 
WITH p, collect(hvo) as hvos 
WHERE size(hvos) = size( [1,2,3,4,5]) return count(p)
```

Is it possible to rewrite it with `exists` or something like this?

I need to effectively check that `p` has `:HAS_VOTE_ON` on all `c` where `c` in the provided list of`Ids`. What is the most effective way to do such check? I need to cobine this query in the logical `AND`.. for example - `AND exists {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `ALL` function:

```
MATCH (c:Criterion)
WHERE c.id IN [1,2,3,4,5]
WITH COLLECT(c) AS criterias
MATCH (p:Profile)
WHERE ALL(criteria IN criterias WHERE (p)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(criteria))
RETURN count(p)
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately proposed query shows too many DB hits (

Comment: Yeah, this might take a few db hits. But do check your query once, in your query only those `Criterion` nodes will be fetched, which have `Profile` linked to them. If it's expected then it's fine

Comment: Also in your query, since you are comparing sizes of collections. It might give false positives if one profile is linked to one Criterion with more than one `HAS_VOTE_ON` relation.

Answer (score 1):

This query is using EXISTS in the WHERE clause to check if Profile HAS_VOTE_ON all five Criterion.

```
MATCH (p:Profile)
WHERE ALL(cid in [1,2,3,4,5] 
   WHERE EXISTS((p)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(:Criterion {id: cid})))
RETURN count(p)
```

Kindly do a profiling to see if it will perform well.